# Real-time monitoring technique

Tags: .net, c++, real-time, antivirus

Most known AntiVirus software has a real-time monitoring feature, which means it can scan files before been accessed or executed. How a technique like this can be implemented? There is something in .NET called `filewatcher` I don't know if this is the same idea of what is used in AntiVirus.

Comment: I don't know why there are some negative down-votes about the question?

Comment: Me neither. This is by no means a bad question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, antivirus software will install a filter driver that attaches to a file-system driver in the Windows kernel. All requests towards the file-system driver are thus first delivered to the filter, which then determines whether to forward or deny the request.

Note that hooking Windows API or any other API in user-mode is generally not sufficient, as malicious software can always issue calls to the kernel directly, bypassing the hooked API.

Answer (score 1):

Hooking a (Win)API functions is a general solution for such tasks but I suppose this is just a tip of the iceberg.  There is little note about it in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_protection) (`Detection` subsection).  Thus, you need to learn about how to hook API functions and about Windows internals in general.  I would suggest [Windows via C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624240) as a good start point for solving this global problem.